# How Do I disable the "gii" code generator for non admin user?

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

I am using Yii 1.13 framework for my project, I need "gii" code generator but I want to restrict it for admin user only, How can I achieve this ?

Comment: gii is a developer tool and and should not normally be made available to authenticated users. Look at implementing .htaccess to restrict all access for your production server, or delete the functions from your live deployment.

Answer (score 2):

**Follow the below steps:-**

1. Copy the **gii** module from **system.gii** i.e **framework/gii**
2. Paste it inside the **protected/modules** folder of project.
3. Make the following changes in the **GiiModule.php** in your **gii module**.

**Change this**

```
public function beforeControllerAction($controller, $action)
    {   

      if(parent::beforeControllerAction($controller, $action))
        {
            $route=$controller->id.'/'.$action->id;
            if(!$this->allowIp(Yii::app()->request->userHostAddress) && $route!=='default/error')
                throw new CHttpException(403,"You are not allowed to access this page.");

           $publicPages=array(
                'default/login',
                'default/error',
            );

           if(Yii::app()->user->isGuest  && !in_array($route,$publicPages))
                   Yii::app()->user->loginRequired();
            // check your admin conditions here
           elseif(!isset(Yii::app()->user->isAdmin) || !Yii::app()->user->isAdmin)
                   throw new CHttpException(403,"You are not allowed to access this page.");
            else
                return true;
          }
        return false;
    }
```

4. In your **config/main.php**

   `'modules' => 
             array(
               'gii'=>array(
                   'class'=>'application.modules.gii.GiiModule',
                   'password'=> Your password,
                   'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
               ),
           ),`

**Note:-** I haven't tested it. But it might give you an idea about how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict user by IP or choose a password for Gii tool according to it's [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii)

```
return array(
    ......
    'modules'=>array(
        'gii'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password'=>'pick up a password here',
            // 'ipFilters'=>array(...a list of IPs...),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: This is not what OP is asking. Even if an unauthenticated user knows the password, he can use the Gii tool.

Comment: @Touqeer Shafi I know IP based filter but if normal user knows password he can easily access, I want to prevent normal user from accessing "gii" even login page

Comment: @GaneshGhalame how will normal user knows password for gii tool, as this password was saved in your config files ?

Comment: @Touqeer Shafi, My question is disabling the module, even though normal user knows or doesn't know the password he can access the "gii" login page, why should system show them the even login page as of logically when not authorized.

Comment: @GaneshGhalame Gii tool is created only for development purpose it is not recommended that you use it on production server. so just remove it from the modules array in config files that make sense ?